# IFormFile vs byte[] in .NET Core and file upload best practice

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, file-upload, rest, iformfile

I'm designing a REST API controller with .NET CORE so I can upload a file, should I use IFormFile or byte[] in my model's request ?

```
It's better to do this ?

public class AttachmentModel
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
   }

or this ?

public class AttachmentModel
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public IFormFile  FileContent { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: If you pass the uploaded file from the view to the controller, I think `IFormFile` will be a better choice.But if you finally want to save the uploaded file content to the database, you still have to convert it to `byte[]` type for storage.` IFormFile` and `byte[]` types can be mutually converted, so which field type you choose will depend on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, regarding performance, which one is better IFormFile or byte[] ?

Comment: I thought use `IFormFile` is a better choice.Because it's convenient for us to pass file from view to action.